# How do I extract text from a file to a variable while also replacing that text with a marker?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, text-processing

I have a file of `property: value;` pairs (it's CSS). I want to go through this file and regex extract certain values to shell variables, while replacing the text in the file with a marker.

Eg for FILE1:

```
position: float;
background: url("data:image/loremipsum");
height: auto;
background: url("data:image/loremipsum2");
```

And let's say I want to extract and save the image urls to an array:

```
FILE1=path/to/file1
URL[0]=$(echo "$FILE1" | grep "data:image" | awk ???)
# Expected: "data:image/loremipsum"
URL[1]=$(echo "$FILE1" | grep "data:image" | awk ???)
# Expected: "data:image/loremipsum2"
```

And then, from where I extracted the text, that text is replaced with "MARKER0", "MARKER1", and so on.

I'm assuming that the solution for this would involve awk but I typed `man awk` and my head nearly came off. Assuming that I know how to write the regex for this, where do I start?

Do I need awk? Do I need a loop to iterate through each of the image values?

Comment: Are you trying to transform each instance of `data:image...` in a file? If so, finding instances and replacing them with markers like this is not a good approach. Can you add some background info?

Comment: @that other guy; I'm using a not-very-robust minification script that doesn't do a good job of preserving complex image data. I'm removing the image data, replacing it with a simpler value, minifying, and then re-inserting the unminified image data afterwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
arr=($(awk '/background/ && match($0,/\".*\"/){print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)}' Input_file))
OR to use a variable's value for awk as an input then try following.
arr=($(echo "$VAR" | awk '/background/ && match($0,/\".*\"/){print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)}'))
```

To print the array's values try following then.

```
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
  echo "$i"
done
```

Or to print in proper knowing element's index value too with print of array's value try following.

```
count=0
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
  echo "arr["$count"]=$i"
  count=$((count + 1))
done
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** Since OP is saying there could be space in between values. So possible solution for this could be printing values from `awk` command with a new character between the values(which will work as a field separator for BASH array's iterations), I have taken `%` so when you run awk command it will give follows.(using test values in output shown here)

```
awk '/background/ && match($0,/\".*\"/){val=val?val "%" substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2):substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)} END{print val}' Input_file

singh:test/ bla_bla_bla%singh:bla1/bla2
```

Run following command to create array named `arr`.

```
arr=($(awk '/background/ && match($0,/\".*\"/){val=val?val "%" substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2):substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)} END{print val}' Input_file))
```

Now if we set `IFS='%'` and run following command.

```
echo "${arr[0]}"
singh:test/ bla_bla_bla
echo "${arr[1]}"
singh:bla1/bla2
```

Since it has taken new seprator as `%` so it will NOT break values for which have space in them.

Comment: Oh this is perfect for extracting the values! I think I should be able to replace the text from the original file with the markers using sed

Comment: I'm not certain, but I think that your first solution might be taking all of the matches and assigning it to a single value with newlines between matches - `echo "${#arr[@]}"` outputs 1

Comment: @DemonicLocust, when I run ` echo "${#arr[@]}"` it gives me `2`. Please run  my `awk` commands again and check that. Kindly do let me know on same. I edited my solutions a bit. We should get elements in different indexes of array.

Comment: Oh, I was missing the wrapping parentheses on the initial definition! My bad, sorry

Comment: Sorry to bother you again - when the image value contains spaces, awk breaks the value up and puts it into different parts of the arr. Do you know how to prevent this?

Comment: @DemonicLocust, let me check once.

Comment: @DemonicLocust, please try my EDIT solution now. I am setting `IFS='%'` you could choose any character which is NOT coming in your Input_file. But remember change it in `IFS` as well as `awk` code too from `%` to whatever new character you like.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd use simpler tools. In this case, `grep -o` and bash arrays. (You haven't specified which shell you're using, so I'll assume it's bash.)

```
images=($(egrep -o 'data:image/[^"]+' input.css))
```

Or if you prefer:

```
images=($(egrep -o 'url\("data:image/[^"]+"' input.css))
images=(${images[@]#url(\"}); images=(${images[@]%\"})
```

These both create an array, `images[]`, which you can view a number of ways:

```
$ declare -p images
declare -a images='([0]="data:image/loremipsum" [1]="data:image/loremipsum2")'
$ printf '%s\n' "${images[@]}"
data:image/loremipsum
data:image/loremipsum2
```

Now .. data:images/ values *should not* contain spaces. If they do, this solution will have problems because array content splits on whitespace by default.  If you REALLY think you need to preserve whitespace, you can do that with by reading your input in a loop:

```
$ cat input.css
position: float;
background: url("data:image/loremipsum");
height: auto;
background: url("data:image/loremipsum 2");
$ images=(); while read -r; do images+=("$REPLY"); done < <(egrep -o 'data:image/[^"]+' input.css)
$ declare -p images
declare -a images='([0]="data:image/loremipsum" [1]="data:image/loremipsum 2")'
```

If your values contain newlines ... then you're on your own. :-)